# Redirect input with subprocess python

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I use input redirection `<()` with python's `subprocess.Popen`?

For example, say I have:

```
import subprocess


class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(["sort file1.txt file2.txt)"],
                                     shell=True,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            line = self.proc.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                raise StopIteration
            return line.strip().decode('utf-8')


t = Test()
for line in t:
    print(line)
```

The above works perfectly fine, but really I need the command to do something like:

```
sort <(python file1.txt) <(python file2.txt)
```

That doesnt seem to run anything though, even this doesnt work

```
sort <(cat file1.txt) <(cat file2.txt)
```

How can I get this to work with python's subprocess, and iterate through the results line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell subprocess.Popen() to use `/bin/bash`, which supports the `<(..)` syntax, instead of the default `/bin/sh`, which doesn't:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(["sort <(cat file1.txt) <(cat file2.txt)"],
                                     shell=True,
                                     executable="/bin/bash",
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            line = self.proc.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                raise StopIteration
            return line.strip().decode('utf-8')


t = Test()
for line in t:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Great, that works perfectly